# ES6: Constructor function getters and setters

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, getter-setter

Why can't I set getters and setters in this way inside of the Constructor function?

```
function zConstructor(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    
    set fullname(text) {
        const parts = text.split(' ');
        this.firstName = parts[0];
        this.lastName = parts[1];
    }

    get fullname() {
        return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    }
}
```

This getters and setters way works only in classes and Factory functions. What is the reason?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't because the syntax of the language does not allow you to do it, at least not that way.

Comment: @Pointy only because the syntax of the language doesn't allow it? that's the reason?

Comment: what kind of reason are you looking for?

Comment: Why would you want to define a new setter and getter every time the constructor is called? They ought to live on the prototype object!

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do it, but a constructor function is just a function, and the syntax of ordinary code blocks does not include the creation of setter and getter functions; there's no way to even make sense of what your code is supposed to mean, as far as the parser is concerned.

What you can do is use `Object.defineProperties()` to add the properties. Or, probably better, is to create them on the prototype either directly (again, with `Object.defineProperties()`), or by using a `class` declaration:

```
function zConstructor(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    
    Object.defineProperties(this, {
        fullname: {
            set: function(text) {
                const parts = text.split(' ');
                this.firstName = parts[0];
                this.lastName = parts[1];
            },
            get: function() {
                return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Oh I understood, Thanks!

Comment: So only the syntax of Factory function and Class enables set getters and setters in my way. right?

Comment: @Drenky yes. Again, a constructor function is just a normal function; there is no special syntax for the body of a constructor function. The special syntax is available in a `class` declaration.

Comment: right, but it's a function that you can use the new to create an instance. Is the new available in all functions? @Pointy

Comment: @Drenky yes, except when you use `class` syntax to create a constructor. It's also possible internally for the runtime to provide functions that *cannot* be used as a constructor, but if you write a simple `function xyz() { ... }` you can write `new xyz()`. Note that there is absolutely nothing different about the syntax for creating a constructor function and the syntax for creating a regular function.

Answer (score 0):

A proper way of doing this is:

```
function zConstructor(firstName, lastName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
}
zConstructor.prototype = {
  set fullname(text) {
    const parts = text.split(" ");
    this.firstName = parts[0];
    this.lastName = parts[1];
  },

  get fullname() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
  },
};
```

Your code does not work because setters and getters are meaningful for Objects only.